# Xamarin Forms: slow httpclient and database access

Tags: android, performance, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms beginner here :)

Ok, so here's the deal. I've build a native Android+Kotlin app which uses some of the sdk components (LiveData, ViewModel, Room) and other goodies (dagger2) and it works just fine.

I've been trying to port this app into Xamarin Forms so that I can also get an iOS version. Even though I've managed to reproduce the UI, I'm having some problems with web services and database access: both are really really slow! Much slower than the results I was getting when using kotlin!

For instance, while in kotlin calling a local web service wouldn't be longer than some milliseconds, in xamarin it takes several seconds! Here's the code I'm using:

```
public class NewsService : INewsService {
    private const string _url = "https://...";
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    public NewsService(HttpClient client) {
        _client = client;
    }
    public async Task<IEnumerable<DbNews>> GetAllNewsAsync() {
        try {
            var response = await _client.GetAsync(_url);
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                // TODO: log here instead of throwing?
                throw new Exception("An error occurred during web service call.");
            }

            var responseText = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var newsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<DbNews>>(responseText);
            return newsList;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.Fail(ex.ToString());
            return Enumerable.Empty<DbNews>();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using DI with autofac. HttpClient is being registered as a singleton:

```
containerBuilder.Register(c => SetupDefaultHttpClient())
                        .As<HttpClient>()
                        .SingleInstance();
```

`SetupDefaultHttpClient` is a simple helper which sets up authorization header (basic authentication). I've already checked the android project settings and it looks like it's setup to use the native handler:

[image]

Another pain point is accessing the db: it's also way slower that in the kotlin app. With kotlin, I was using Room. With Xamarin Forms, I'm using [SQLite.net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/data-access/using-sqlite-orm). The mappings are really simple: we're talking about an object with primitive properties (string, ints, datetime) which are directly mapped into the columns of an existing table.

Here's the code I've written for updating the news in the local database (it's run after calling the web service):

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<SimplifiedNews>> UpdateNewsListAsync(IEnumerable<DbNews> news) {
    if (!news?.Any() ?? true) {
        return Enumerable.Empty<SimplifiedNews>(); // empty collection do nothing
    }

    await _db.RunInTransactionAsync(cnn => {
                                        try {
                                            cnn.DeleteAll<DbNews>();
                                            cnn.InsertAll(news,
                                                          typeof(DbNews));
                                            cnn.Commit();
                                        }
                                        catch (Exception ex) {
                                            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
                                        }

                                    });
    var simplifiedNews = news.Select(n => n.ToSimplifiedNews())
                             .ToList();
    return simplifiedNews;
}
```

The problem here is that the data saved in the database should be refreshed (if possible) when the app is run. Since that means calling a web service and saving it on a local db, the user experience ends up being really bad! (the splash screen is displayed for several seconds before the main page is rendered - I've changed the loading into the splash screen so that the user doesn't stare a blank page for several seconds)

Am I doing something wrong here? Any tips on how to investigate these problems? I mean, is there anything that might make calling a web service way slower in xamarin forms than in a kotlin app? How can I investigate this sort of problems?

THanks.

Comment: Here is link about improve http performance, 
 http://jonathanpeppers.com/Blog/improving-http-performance-in-xamarin-applications, you can refer to it.

Comment: I've followed those steps...and still pretty slow when compared with kotlin...

Comment: Xamarin forms not only support for android, it support other platfoms, so I think a bit slow, it could be accepted, did you ensure these application running in same network environment and android device?